# Laravel form validator error

Tags: php, laravel, api, validation, laravel-5.3

I want to validate the input fields before storing the data in database so i went through the laravel docs and followed these

1. `php artisan make:request StoreLessons`
2. in `StoreLessons`

   ```
   public function rules()
       {
           return [
               'title' => 'required|unique:lesson',
               'body' => 'required',
           ];
       }
   ```
3. in my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Response;
use App\lesson;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreLessons;

class LessonsController extends ApiController 
{

    protected $lessonTransformer;

    function __construct(LessonTransformer $lessonTransformer) 
    {
        $this->lessonTransformer = $lessonTransformer;
    }

    //fetch all and pass a metadata 'data' 
    public function index() 
    {
        $lessons = Lesson::all();

        return $this->respond([
            'data' => $this->lessonTransformer->transformCollection($lessons->all())
        ]);
    }

    //add a new lesson to lessons table
    public function store(StoreLessons $request) 
    {
        Lesson::create($request->all());

        //Lesson::create(input::all());

        return $this->respondCreated('Lesson created successfully');
    }


}
```

now i'm getting this error

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 770:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel_api.lesson' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `lesson` where `title` = the)
```

i don't know why it's looking for `lesson` table i have a `lessons` table

but the `store()` function works with default validation

```
//this works fine but i wan to do the validation 
    public function store() 
    {
        if (! input::get('title') or ! input::get('body')) {
            return $this->respondBadRequest();
        }

        Lesson::create(input::all());

        return $this->respondCreated('Lesson created successfully');
    }
```

Thank You

Comment: Not related to your question, however, according to laravel naming convention, your Model name should be `Lesson` and not `lesson`. So this model will automatically find the table `lessons` in your database.

Comment: hey thanks for your time, it was a mistake at `unique:lesson` changed to `lessons`

Comment: I mean not in your validation rule, but the name of the model.  `use App\lesson` should be `use App\Lesson`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unique:table,column,except,idColumn
```

The unique syntax goes as above and the first parameter passed is the table name.

```
public function rules() { 
    return [ 'title' => 'required|unique:lesson', 'body' => 'required', ];
}
```

The unique rule here looks for a table `lesson`. Try changing that to `lessons`

Comment: thank you so much that worked , can you please tell me how to pass the errors as `JSON` to the view, now if i send the request with empty fields i'm getting redirect  to `welcom.blabe.php`

Comment: Once you have passed for validation, just do this if there is validation errors. `return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422)`. Here the `$validator` is the results of your validation

Comment: can you please tell me how do i do it in my method i have to return the success as well as the failure  `public function store(StoreLessons $request) 
 {
  Lesson::create($request->all());
  
  return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422)

  //Lesson::create(input::all());

  return $this->respondCreated('Lesson created successfully');
 }`

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-display-validation-errors-of-ajax-requests), Laravel 5.3 by default sends an error with status code 422. So remove the above line I suggested in the controller. And in your ajax, `error function` console.log(respnsoe). Check PHPMick answer there.

Comment: i'm building an API so i don't have `ajax` as such so i wonder how to send those error messages as JSON, if possible can you please post some example code, as you said i'm not getting any laravel default messages with 422, i'm using postman to test the API so when i post with empty feilds i 'm seeing the laravel home page

Comment: @MrRobot in `Postman` check the status code to see if 422 was returned. Sorry that I have not worked a lot with `laravel 5.3`, I am not able to assist you on that. You could try posting that as another question and someone out there would be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please write below line after related model class name like this.

**class xyz extends Model
{**
protected $table = 'lessons';

code---

**}**

Try this.